# creating a new project that doesn't use androidx

Tags: xml, android-studio, gradle, androidx

Does any one know how can I create a new android studio project that doesn't use androidx? or maybe migrating back an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, at the top where it says Refactor, go to 
`Refactor > Migrate to AppCompat`.
Then, choose whether you want to back up your project, and click `Migrate`.